# Opengl Lighting and Normals

Tags: c, opengl

I'm currently experimenting with opengl and glut.
As i have like no idea what i'm doing i totally mess up with the lighting.
The complete compilable file can be found here: [main.c](http://pastebin.com/uMeK8rBy)

I have a  display loop which currently operates like following:

`glutDisplayFunc(also idle func)`:

> 1. `glClear` `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`
> 2. switch to modelview matrix
> 3. load identity
> 4. first Rotate and then Translate according to my keyboard and mouse inputs for the camera
> 5. draw a ground with `glNormal` 0,1,0 and `glMaterial` on front and back,
>      which is encapsulated by push/popmatrix
> 6. pushmatrix
> 7. translate
> 8. `glutSolidTeapod`
> 9. popmatrix
> 10. do lighting related things, glEnable GL_LIGHTING and LIGHT0 and passing
>       float pos[] = {0.1,0.1,-0.1,0.1};
>           glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos );
> 11. swap the buffers

the function associated with
`glutReshapeFunc` operates(this is from the lighthouse3d.com glut tutorial):

> 1. calculate the ratio of the screen
> 2. switch to projection matrix
> 3. loadidentity
> 4. set the viewport
> 5. set the perspective
> 6. switch to modelview matrix

However this all seems to work somehow,
but as i enable lighting, the normals seem to totally mess up.
[image: gl_lighting1]

My GL_LIGHT0 seems to stay as it should, as i can see the lightspot on the ground
not moving, as i move around
[image: gl_lighting2]

And the Teapods texture seem to move if i move my camera,
the teapod itself stands still.

Here is some visual material to explain it,
i apologize for my bad english : /

[Link to YouTube video describing visually](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvXPje9vl50)

Comment: 1: Add the code to the question itself! 2: Don't dump so much code into a question at all, narrow it down to the main problem! 3: Stop using old, outdated and deprecated OpenGL functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You have a series of mistakes in your code:

1. You don't properly set the properties of your OpenGL window:

   ```
   glutCreateWindow (WINTITLE);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
   ```

   The `glutInitDisplayMode` will only affect any windows you create *after* that. You should swap those two lines.
2. You never enable the depth test. You should add `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` after you created the windows. Not using the depth test expalins the weird "see-through" effect you get with the teapot.
3. You have the following code

   ```
   glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE | GL_CULL_FACE_MODE);
   ```

   This is wrong in two ways: the `GLenums` are not single bits, but just values. You cannot OR them together and expect anything useful to happen. I don't know if this particular call will enable something you don't expect or just generate an error.

   The second issue here is that `GL_CULL_FACE_MODE` isn't even a valid enum to enable.

   In your case, you either skip the `CULL_FACE` completely, or you should write

   ```
   glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
   glFrontFace(GL_CW);
   ```

   The latter call changes the face orientation from OpenGL's default *counterclokcwise* rule to the *clockwise* one, as the GLUT teapot is defined that way. Interestingly, your floor is also drawn following that rule, so it will fit for your whole scene. At least for now.
4. You have not fully understood how GL's state machine works. You draw the scene and *then* set the lighting. But this will not have an effect on the already drawn objects. It just affects the next time you draw something, which will be in the next frame here. Now, the lighting of the fixed function pipeline works in eye space. That means that if you want a light source which is located at a fixed position in the world, and not in a fixed position relativ to the camera, you have to re-specify the light position, with the updated modelview matrix, everytime the camera moves. In your case, the light source will lag behind one frame when the camera moves. This is probably not noticeable, but still wrong in principle. You should reorder your `display()` function to

   ```
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   control (WALKSPEED, MOUSESPEED, mousein);
   lightHandler();
   drawhelpgrid(1, 20);
   drawTeapod();
   glutSwapBuffers();
   ```

With those changes, I can actually get the expected result of a lighted teapot on my system. But as I side note I feel obligded to warn you that almost all of your code relies on *deprecated* features of OpenGL. This stuff has been *removed* from modern versions of OpenGL. If you start learning OpenGL now, you should consider learning the modern programmable pipeline, and not some decades old obsolete stuff.